# Select Only one result for each user id for a "chat history"

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to return only one (latest) row of each UserId if contained in MySQL DB to have results show a "chat history" per-say.  Basically like a test history overview of the latest message to or from any other user.

```
<?php
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql://hostname=localhost;dbname=data_base', 'user', 'password');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id`='{$userId}' OR `to_id`='{$userId}' ORDER BY `stamp` DESC");
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: append `LIMIT 1` to the query, also shouldn't it be `mysql:hostname=etc..`? Also learn how to prepare statements. You're wide open to MySQL injection attacks, that is even if you care about your data being stolen.

Comment: I like to start with the simplest code to remove any possible complications and perhaps I asked the question wrong but setting LIMIT 1 only returns a single entry total. What I need is all results but if more than one entry is to or from $userId it only gives the latest entry for each `from_id` or `to_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql://hostname=localhost;dbname=data_base', 'user', 'password');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id`='{$userId}' OR `to_id`='{$userId}' GROUP BY `from_id`, `to_id` ORDER BY `stamp` DESC");
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```